# Add bottom shadow to the image

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

How can I add shadow to the image like it done on the sample picture?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it in your xml file use the attribute elevation

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

otherwise you can do it programatically

youImageView.setElevation(8);

Comment: That will look exactly nothing like the example image.